# Printing BufferedImage on JPanel

Tags: java, swing

I am trying to display a BufferedImage onto a JPanel but when I run the program it doesn't display anything.

I imagine it is a problem with creation of the BufferedImage but, with my limited understanding of Java, I have no idea what that problem might be. Also I would appreciate some more information about the paintComponent method (what does super.paintComponent(g) mean?)

Main.java

```
public class Main {
 public static void main (String[] args) {
  Window.windowMake("This is a window");
 }
}
```

Window.java

```
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Window extends JFrame {
 public static void windowMake(String title) {
  JFrame jf = new JFrame();
  jf.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
  jf.setSize(300,300);
  jf.setVisible(true);
  jf.setTitle(title);
  jf.add(new Paint());
 }
}
```

Paint.java

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.File;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Paint extends JPanel {
 BufferedImage sprite = new
 BufferedImage(60,60,BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_ARGB);

 public void createBufImg() {
  try {
   sprite = ImageIO.read(new File("/Images/Scene.png"));
   System.out.println("File read");
  } catch (IOException e) {
   System.out.println("Could not read image");
  }
 }

 @Override
  public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
  super.paintComponent(g);
  g.drawImage(sprite,20,20,this);
 }
}
```

Comment: the code doesnt even compile the line BufferedImage sprite = new; isnt a valid syntex

Comment: It was compiling earlier... I guess I changed the line between when i last ran the code and when I copied and pasted it.

Comment: back to top (I don't know if that works on this site)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a constructor to class `Paint` that creates the sprite and your program will show the image.

```
public Paint() {
    super();
    createBufImg();
}
```

Also, you should generally not be calling your classes with the same names as classes or methods in Swing, that gets too confusing. So don't make a classes called `Main`, `Panel` and `Window`.

> what does super.paintComponent(g) mean

It calls the `paintComponent` method of the super class, ie the class you are extending (`JPanel` in this instance). I suggest you look things up on the internet about painting in Swing for more details.

Comment: @CharlieLandrigan Probably because the image file is not located where you're looking for it with `new File("/Images/Scene.png")`. Instead of a relative path, try an absolute path (eg `C:/Temp/Scene.png`). The way you are looking for the image in your code is with a path relative to the location where you are running the program from. This has to be exact for the file to be found.

Comment: I got rid of the first "/" and that fixed it, thanks so much for your help!